# How to find a model number that replaced an old Shimano part

Tags: brakes, shimano, parts

Is there some listing of Shimano component model numbers that can help me find a currently-manufactured part that is equivalent to an old model number that is no longer being manufactured?

In particular, I'm looking to find a currently-manufactured replacement for a Deore LX V-brake, model number BR-M570.

This brake pivots around an internal sleeve built into the brake arm rather than pivoting directly on the cantilever brake post. I need something like this since my brake posts are corroded and will not be a good bearing surface.

Comment: Are your canti studs threadded?  Might be a better solution to replace them, or look for a whole replacement fork.

Comment: HAH I googled for "shimano BR-M570 replacement" and this question is now the top match.   There are a lot of ebay hits for this model number too.

Comment: @Criggie no, the studs on my frame are not threaded as some are in order to be swapped out, and it's the rear ones that are corroded, so it's not as easy as swapping a fork, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

I hate to say this, but You're going to have to make a trip to your local bike shop. Chances are, if they're in the US, and they carry Shimano parts, they buy from Quality Bicycle Products (QBP). The company has an online catalog which you can search part numbers both active ant inactive, as well as related models. This catalog is only accessible to bicycle shops, and not the general public (though feel free to open your own shop, we only need more of them :-) ).

They'll be more than happy to assist you there, and hopefully find you an answer.

Now, buyer beware that this is only a guess, but based upon the internal levering mechanism that you describe, the [BR-M580](https://si.shimano.com/pdfs/ev/EV-BR-M580-2361B.pdf) looks to be the successor in the LX parts line. I see the same mechanical features, but from an upgraded parts standpoint. Like I said, only the parts shop will know for sure.

Now onto the actual question; the process. The [shimano parts website](https://si.shimano.com/#/en/search/) holds a database of some of their part numbers. I simply searched your part number preceeder, the series, and the line (eg "BR-M DEORE LX") and I sifted through the disk brakes, and found similar pad brakes in a higher line.